# Room is really a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, tv, spaceship, young-adult

When I was a kid - 80's/90's - there was a science fiction series about a kid, whose room was really a spaceship that could just take off detaching itself from the building. Can anyone help me on the name of that tv show.

Comment: Hi userid15784.  Can you provide any additional details which might help in identifying this series?  e.g. was it live action? animated?  If animated was it anime style?  Any detail at all might help jog someone's memory.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it was live action, not animated. I do not clearly remember the plot, but the kid used his spaceship to do missions in space. I cannot provide much more info, since I cannot remember it in clearer details, but it was awesome :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, doing a search on IMDB and Wiki, I found the following Danish live action shows from 1984 called Crash. Does any of the following ring a bell?

> The main character in the series is ten-year-old Birger, who collects the comic book series Thunderboy. When his parents discover one day that the first issue is worth 10,000 kroner, the family searches the entire house for his copy but fails to find it. In frustration, Birger kicks the furniture in his room and discovers that the room functions as a spaceship. He takes off, and in outer space discovers a supervillain named Barry Slisk, who had stolen his comic book. Slisk has his hideout in a black hole and Birger must try to thwart his evil plans. In the course of doing so he meets a beautiful girl named Iris, who helps him.

[Wiki Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash_%281984_TV_series%29)

[IMDB Description](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0389599/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl)

[Episode Guide](http://thetvdb.com/?tab=seasonall&id=251414&lid=7)

Comment: I think that might be right. Thanks, I'll check it out. It has been driving me crazy, so I hope you're right :)

Comment: It was absolutely correct. Thank you very much